# How to read csv file pieces and put into single pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, python-requests

I have multiple chunked bin files that I can download from urls:

```
sample file1 from url1:
BibNumber,ItemBarcode,ItemType,Collection,CallNumber,CheckoutDateTime
1898883,0010047377493,jcbk,ncfic,J LEWIS,04/21/2009 07:46:00 PM
2496852,0

sample file2 from url2:
010061167887,acbk,nanf,291.4 L5664S 2000,02/05/2009 11:41:00 AM

sample file3 from url3:
1898883,0010047377493,jcbk,ncfic,J LEWIS,04/21/2009 07:46:00 PM
```

As you can see, these files were originally from the same csv file and were split into many pieces. And it's possible that they were split in the middle of a row. (For the sample above, the second row exists in both file1 and file2)

Now I need to download these files from url and read them into one pandas dataframe. I have tried reading these files into a tempfile and then convert to dataframe:

```
        with tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile(mode="a+", suffix=".csv") as temp_csv:
            for url in urls:
                temp_csv.write(get(url).text)
            temp_csv.flush()
            temp_csv.seek(0)

            df = pd.read_csv(
                temp_csv.name,
                sep=None,  # when set to None, auto-detection is used
                engine="python",
                quotechar=quotechar,
                names=self._get_columns(namespace, table_name)
                if not include_header
                else None,
            )
```

It works but quite slow for large files. It would be great if I could read and write to the dataframe directly. What's the most efficient way to read these file pieces into a pandas dataframe?

Comment: If you have the memory for it, can you combine the files in memory with StringIO and create the dataframe from that?

Comment: Hi Krewsayder, thank you for the comment! I just tried StringIO, and it's definitly faster than writing to a tempfile! I'm just wondering if it's possible to write directly to the dataframe?

Comment: What would your dataframe look like if you could write directly to it?

Comment: I definitely think it would be hard, if not impossible to write directly to a dataframe since you're files end mid field.